# If two people speak like this, does it mean they agree or disagree?: A- “I don’t think he’s coming.” B- “Well, I think so.”

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language

**A- “I don’t think he’s coming.”**

**B- “Well, I think so.”**

When I think about B's answer, **"Well, I think so."** I had the impression that B thinks in the same way as A does. So, B, too, thinks he is not coming.

But then it also seemed ambiguous. If **"I think so"** means **"yes"**, then B doesn't agree with A, and B wants to mean **"Yes, he is coming."**

To sum up, I am not quite sure whether B agrees with A or disagrees with A, because I am not sure about whether "**I think so"** always means **"Yes"** or it means **"I agree with you."**

So, I want to ask: Does A and B have the same belief that he is not coming, or does A think he is not coming but B thinks he is coming.?

Comment: "Well' beginning a response to a statement often indicates doubt or disagreement.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey So, according to the response, A think he is not coming but B thinks he is coming. So, B disagrees with A. Is that correct?

Comment: B disagrees with A.   B thinks that he is coming.

Answer (score 2):

I (British English) would only reply "I think so" in response to a question. An affirmative answer would be:

> A: Is he coming?
> B: I think so.

There are two negative forms:

> B: I think not. - *formal*
> B: I don't think so. - *informal*

I would use "Well, I think so" to (petulantly) re-affirm my stated opinion after somebody else disagreed with me:

> B: I think the weather will be good at the weekend
> A: I doubt it!
> B: Well, I think so [anyway].

In response to a statement like A's in your example, I would reply with something like the following, depending on the situation.

> I think you're right. - *agree*
> Well, I think he will. - *disagree*